# Why are my product images showing in a new tab?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am very new to Magento and taking over this site from someone else who built it, so be kind in your answers!

Check out any product at `ktmbikeindustries.com` and you'll see that any additional photos besides the main photo open in a new tab, rather than scrolling through right there on the product page. I have checked the theme setup and theme design but after that, I'm not sure where to look to fix this, or what code might be needed to do so (and where to put that code).

Comment: It's mainly related to lightbox issue. I would suggest you to have a look into `template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml`. You can also get support from your theme author.

Comment: Thank you, I assumed this was likely a code-based issue. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing some obvious settings in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

This is a JS problem, `preventDefault` function is not being executed, so when you click the image a new tab is opened, just like it would happen if there was no JS functionality

You'd review JS errors in Firebug console (for instance) & fix them. I see this when browsing a random catalog product view page

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ':' after property name in object at line 1 column 176 of the JSON data
```

So, it seems any of the properties in the JSON object is not well quoted

If you are using any extension, and the problem is general, then you'd claim support for this issue. If you are using Magento default code, then you'd ensure you are not using quote character in labels or image filenames